# Joining to the conditional $\sigma$-algebra any algebra from a subset of the union of two algebra does not change their conditional independence

Tags: measure-theory, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation, independence, monotone-class-theorem

In E. Carnal "Markov Properties for Certain Random Fields", there is a lemma 2.2 (ii) which states:

If $\mathscr{A}\perp\mathscr{B}\mid\mathscr{C}$, $\mathscr{D}\subseteq\mathscr{A}\cup\mathscr{B}$ where $\cup$ is the union of set families, then $\mathscr{A}\perp\mathscr{B}\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})$.

I want to prove this. Any insights? Many Thanks!!!

---

I've tried in this way: For any $A\in\mathscr{A}$, $B\in\mathscr{B}$, $\Lambda\in\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})$ or $$\Lambda\in\mathscr{K}:=\left\{C\cap D: C\in\mathscr{C}, D\in\sigma(\mathscr{D})\right\},$$ does it somehow hold that
\begin{align*}
    (*)
    \int_{\Lambda}\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_B\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\right\}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}
    =
    \int_{\Lambda}\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{1}_A\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\right\}\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{1}_B\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\right\}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}?
\end{align*}

I've also noticed that

(1) $\sigma(\mathscr{D})\subseteq\mathscr{A}\vee\mathscr{B}$;

(2)
\begin{align*}
    \text{LHS of (*)}
    &=\int_{\Lambda}\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_B\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\\
&=\int_{C}\mathbb{1}_D\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_B\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\\
    &=\cdots;
\end{align*}

(3)
\begin{align*}
    \text{RHS of (*)}
    &=\int_{\Lambda}\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{1}_B\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\right\}\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\right\}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\\
    &=\int_{\Lambda}\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{1}_B\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\right\}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P}\\
    &=\int_{C}\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{1}_D\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{E}\left\{\mathbb{1}_B\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\right\}\mid\mathscr{C}\right\}\,\mathrm{d}\mathbb{P};
\end{align*}
Well, I can hardly apply the condition $\mathscr{A}\perp\mathscr{B}\mid\mathscr{C}$, and can hardly convert between $\mathscr{C}$ and $\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})$.

---

I also tried in this way, which I think is fairly close to the whole proof. Suppose $C\cap D$ is any atom of $\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})$, where $C$ is any atom of $\mathscr{C}$, and $D$ is any atom of $\sigma(\mathscr{D})$. Since $\mathscr{D}\subseteq\mathscr{A}\cup\mathscr{B}$ rather than $\mathscr{A}\vee\mathscr{B}$, we can show that $D$ is of the form $D=A_0\cap B_0$ where $A_0\in\mathscr{A}$ and $B_0\in\mathscr{B}$. Therefore, on any atom $C\cap D$ of $\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})$, it holds that, $\forall A\in\mathscr{A}$, $\forall B\in\mathscr{B}$,
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{P}(A\cap B\cap C\cap D)\mathbb{P}(C\cap D)\mathbb{P}^2(C)
    &=\mathbb{P}((A\cap A_0)\cap(B\cap B_0)\cap C)\mathbb{P}(C)\mathbb{P}(A_0\cap B_0\cap C)\mathbb{P}(C)\\
    &=\mathbb{P}(A\cap A_0\cap C)\mathbb{P}(B\cap B_0\cap C)\mathbb{P}(A_0\cap C)\mathbb{P}(B_0\cap C)\\
    &=\mathbb{P}(A\cap A_0\cap C)\mathbb{P}(B_0\cap C)\mathbb{P}(B\cap B_0\cap C)\mathbb{P}(A_0\cap C)\\
    &=\mathbb{P}(A\cap A_0\cap B_0\cap C)\mathbb{P}(C)\mathbb{P}(B\cap B_0\cap A_0\cap C)\mathbb{P}(C)\\
    &=\mathbb{P}(A\cap C\cap D)\mathbb{P}(B\cap C\cap D)\mathbb{P}^2(C),
\end{align*}
where the second and the second to the last equality use the condition $\mathscr{A}\perp\!\!\!\perp\mathscr{B}\mid\mathscr{C}$. Thus, it has been showed that $\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_B\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\}$ and $\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{1}_A\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\}\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{1}_B\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\}$ do match on every atom of $\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})$.

In this approach, I think there are still several issues:

(1) Do the matchings on all atoms suggest the equality $$\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{1}_A\mathbb{1}_B\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\}=\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{1}_A\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\}\mathbb{E}\{\mathbb{1}_B\mid\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D})\};$$

(2) Can the approach still hold when the probability of some atoms, say $C$ and $D$, are zero?

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mathcal A$ and $\mathcal B$ be sub$\sigma$-algebras  of $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr B$ respectively, and $A\in\mathscr A, B\in\mathscr B$ :

If $\mathscr A\perp\mathscr B\quad$ also $\quad\mathscr A\perp\mathscr B\mid\mathcal A\vee\mathcal B$:
$$P_\Omega[A\cap B\mid\mathcal A\vee\mathcal B]=P_\Omega[A\mid\mathcal A]\cdot P_\Omega[B\mid\mathcal B]$$
Conditioned by $\mathscr C$ it would also be:
$$P_{\Omega\mid\mathscr C}[A\cap B\mid\mathcal A\vee\mathcal B]=P_{\Omega\mid\mathscr C}[A\mid\mathcal A]\cdot P_{\Omega\mid\mathscr C}[B\mid\mathcal B]$$
But, in general: $P_{\Omega\mid\mathscr W}[U\mid\mathscr V]=P_\Omega[U\mid\mathscr V\vee\mathscr W]$. Therefore:
$$P_\Omega[A\cap B\mid\mathcal A\vee\mathcal B\vee\mathscr C]=P_\Omega[A\mid\mathcal A\vee\mathscr C]\cdot P_\Omega[B\mid\mathcal B\vee\mathscr C]$$

Answer (score 0):

To prove this lemma, we need to show that for any events $A$ in $\mathscr{A}$ and $B$ in $\mathscr{B}$, we have $P(A \cap B | \mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D})) = P(A|\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D}))P(B|\mathscr{C}\vee\sigma(\mathscr{D}))$.

First, note that since $\mathscr{A} \perp \mathscr{B}|\mathscr{C}$, we have $P(A \cap B|\mathscr{C}) = P(A|\mathscr{C})P(B|\mathscr{C})$.

Now, consider the event $A \cap B$. This event can be written as $(A\cap B\cap \mathscr{C})\cup(A\cap B\cap \mathscr{C}^c)$. Since $\mathscr{A}\perp\mathscr{B}|\mathscr{C}$, we have $A\perp B|\mathscr{C}^c$, which means that $P(A\cap B|\mathscr{C}^c)=P(A|\mathscr{C}^c)P(B|\mathscr{C}^c)$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
P(A \cap B | \mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D})) &= P((A \cap B \cap \mathscr{C}) \cup (A \cap B \cap \mathscr{C}^c) | \mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D}))\\
&= P(A \cap B \cap \mathscr{C} | \mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D})) + P(A \cap B \cap \mathscr{C}^c | \mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D}))\\
&= P(A|\mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D}))P(B|\mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D})) + P(A|\mathscr{C}^c \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D}))P(B|\mathscr{C}^c \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D}))\\
&= P(A|\mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D}))P(B|\mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D}))
\end{align*}

where the second equality follows from the law of total probability and the fact that $A\perp B|\mathscr{C}^c$, and the third equality follows from the definition of conditional probability and the fact that $A$ and $B$ are both in $\mathscr{D}$ or their complements are in $\mathscr{D}$.

Therefore, we have shown that $P(A \cap B | \mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D})) = P(A|\mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D}))P(B|\mathscr{C} \vee \sigma(\mathscr{D}))$, which completes the proof.

Comment: Sorry... Could you tell me what do you mean by $\mathscr{C}^c$ and $A\cap B\cap\mathscr{C}$? Thanks!

Comment: $A \cup B \cup \mathcal{C}$ is shorthand for $(A \cup B) \cup (\bigcup_{C \in \mathcal{C}} C)$, where $\bigcup_{C \in \mathcal{C}} C$ denotes the union of all sets in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: $\mathcal{C}^c = { \omega \in \Omega : \omega \notin C \text{ for all } C \in \mathcal{C} }$.

Comment: Isn't it that the union of all sets in the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{C}$ just the whole space $\Omega$? @Zbigniew

Comment: $A\cup B \cup \mathcal{C}=\bigcup_{C\in \mathcal{C}}(A\cup B \cup B \cup C)$

Comment: You mean $A\cap B\cap\mathscr{C}=\cup_{C\in\mathscr{C}}(A\cap B\cap C)$? @Zbigniew